# Remove substring and merge rows in python/pandas

Tags: python, pandas, merge, substring

my df:

```
   description               total      average      number
0 NFL football (white) L     49693        66       1007
1 NFL football (white) XL    79682        74       1198
2 NFL football (white) XS    84943        81       3792
3 NFL football (white) S     78371        73       3974
4 NFL football (blue) L      99482        92       3978
5 NFL football (blue) M      32192        51       3135
6 NFL football (blue XL      75343        71       2879
7 NFL football (red) XXL     84391        79       1192
8 NFL football (red) XS      34727        57       992
9 NFL football (red) L       44993        63       1562
```

What I would like to do is remove the sizes and be left with a sum total, mean average and sum number for each colour of football:

```
   description               total      average    number
0 NFL football (white)       292689       74       9971
1 NFL football (blue)        207017       71       9992
2 NFL football (red)         164111       66       3746
```

Any suggestions much appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can `groupby` the reformatted `description` field (without modifying original contents of `description`) where the reformatting is done by splitting with a space and exclude the last part by using `.str.split()`, `.str.join()`.  Then aggregate with `.agg()`.

Further reformatting the output to the desired output by rounding up and casting to interger with `.round()` and `.astype()`.

```
(df.groupby(
            df['description'].str.split(' ').str[:-1].str.join(' ')
           )
   .agg({'total': 'sum', 'average': 'mean', 'number': 'sum'})
   .round(0)
   .astype(int)
).reset_index()
```

Result:

```
            description   total  average  number
0   NFL football (blue)  207017       71    9992
1    NFL football (red)  164111       66    3746
2  NFL football (white)  292689       74    9971
```

Answer (score 0):

replace works, but you can also just drop off the last word in the description using rsplit and then do a groupby:

```
df.description = df.description.apply(lambda x: x.rsplit(' ',1)[0])

df.groupby(by='description')[['total', 'number']].sum()
```